# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate a navigation change for frame with URL - How to try catch it

Tags: javascript, security, try-catch

I have this script inside my iframe:

```
var redirectTo = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
try {
      parent.location.href = redirectTo;
}catch(e){
      window.open(redirectTo);
    }
```

The browser wont catch the error in the subject.
I want the browser to do the catch block if the try block was failed.
But, even though the error happens inside the try block, the browser still see the error.

**Update**
In a normal situation, my code working fine.
It does not working when its iframe inside iframe, in these cases I am getting the security error.
Do you have any idea Y? How can I know if my iframe is inside other Iframe?

Thanks

Comment: I dont get error (using chrome), what browser do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by subject? I also don't see the error using Chrome.

Comment: probably because he is doing it to parent frame and i tryed with the self

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch that kind of errors within javascript because its not a javascript error, its a browser security feature.
But you can prevent it by checking domain and port match between the url and current location.
also you can't access the parent frame if its not the same domain/port of your iframe. So if parent frame domain/port is not the same as child iframe its possible that you cant even get the location unless you already know it from other source.
You trying to do something you really shouldn't

(update) **checking parent node**

```
var ploc=null
try {
  if (parent && parent.nodeName=="IFRAME")
    ploc=parent.location;//assuming current node is an iframe
}catch(e){
  //it may be an iframe but from another domain
}

if (ploc) ... //ok its an iframe and is from same domain the we can proceed
```

Comment: well this is another question, "how can i know if my iframe is inside anothe iframe", usually just try access to parent (no need to navigate)

Comment: Thanks, Can you post an example? I don't understand.